# Trying to get property 'nombre' of non-object

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

Tengo una tabla llamada equipos y otra actas , tengo  una tabla pivote llamada acta_equipo con dos llaves foraneas apuntando a equipos , una se llama salida_id y la otra ingreso_id tal como les muestro continuación.

Ahora,quiero pintar en una vista show el nombre de los equipos relacionados al campo salida_id asi como los equipos relacionados al campo ingreso_id pertenecientes a un acta en particular, todo marcha bien hasta que intento acceder al antributo nombre de un equipo. les enseño mi codigo.

mi modelo pivote

```
namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\Equipo;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ActaEquipo extends Model
{
    protected $table='acta_equipo';
    use HasFactory;

    public function acta()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Acta');
    }
    public function equipo()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Equipo');
    }
    public function salida()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Equipo','salida_id');
    } 

    public function ingreso()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Equipo','ingreso_id');
    } 


}
```

esta es la consulta que envia a la vista show.

```
public function show(salida $salida,$id)
    {
        $acta=Acta::findOrfail($id);
        
       
      
        $actaEquipos=ActaEquipo::where('acta_id',$acta->id)->get();
        return view('tecnicos.show',compact('acta','actaEquipos'));
{
```

y asi es como intento pintar los datos.

```
 @foreach ($actaEquipos as $actaEquipo)
 <p>{{$actaEquipo->ingreso->nombre}}  </p>  
 @endforeach
```

lo curioso es que cuando elimino el ->nombre me da este resultado

```
{"id":1,"nombre":"ROUTER","codigo":"DAD334","Nombre_proveedor":"TP-LINK","serial":"00111DA","mac":"11","estado":"NUEVO","observacion":"ANTENA CORTA","destino":"BODEGA","fecha":"2020-01-14","factura_id":1,"img":"IMG.PNG4","created_at":"2020-12-02T02:23:44.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-12-02T02:23:44.000000Z"}

{"id":2,"nombre":"SWITCH","codigo":"024FSD54","Nombre_proveedor":"CISCO","serial":"00111DA","mac":"22DD","estado":"NUEVO","observacion":"ANTENA CORTA","destino":"BODEGA","fecha":"2020-01-14","factura_id":1,"img":"IMG.PNG3","created_at":"2020-12-02T02:23:44.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-12-02T02:23:44.000000Z"}
```

[image: y en mi tabla este registro]

[image: mi resultado con el dd]
[image: asi los pinta en mi vista]

Comment: este es el error que me arroja cuando accedo al atributo nombre.Trying to get property 'nombre' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\proyectos\laravel\Proyect1\resources\views\tecnicos\show.blade.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La consulta que muestras justo así:

```
$actaEquipos=ActaEquipo::where('acta_id',$acta->id)->get();
```

Solamente va a obtener los valores de las llaves foráneas que tu modelo `ActaEquipo` tiene (*una colección de ellas*), derivado de eso es que obtienes el mensaje de error pues dicha colección no lleva cargados los resultados de la relación en cuestión.

Lo anterior siempre lo puedes comprobar directo en el controlador haciendo esto y ver lo que estás recuperando:

```
dd($actaEquipos);
```

Lo que en este punto puedes hacer es:

- Cargar mediante [*eager loading*](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) las relaciones que este guarda con el modelo **`Equipo`** así:

  ```
    $actaEquipos = ActaEquipo::with('ingreso')->whereActaId($acta->id)->get();
  ```

Al final únicamente deberás:

- Iterar con 2 ciclos `foreach` uno para la colección que te devuelve `ActaEquipo` y otro para los registros de la colección que nos retorna la relación `ingreso`

**La iteración sería....**

Considera que esta iteración: **`@foreach($actaEquipo->ingreso as $ingreso)`** solamente debe ocurrir cuando obtienes una colección de ingresos.

```
@foreach($actaEquipos as $actaEquipo)
    /*
        Los datos de la colección principal
    */
    @foreach($actaEquipo->ingreso as $ingreso)
        /*
            Los datos de la colección interna
        */
    @enforeach
@enforeach
```

En caso de que solamente estés obteniendo un objeto de ingreso entonces sería mas o menos así:

```
@foreach($actaEquipos as $actaEquipo)
    /*
        Los datos de la colección principal
    */
    {{ $actaEquipo->ingreso->algoAqui }}
@enforeach
```

- Como extra, yo te recomendaría leer las recomendaciones que da la doc. oficial sobre [declaración de modelos para tablas intermedias](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models).
- Puedes incluir además el uso del helper [optional](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-optional)

Comment: listo ya puedes revisar

Comment: Hola amigo creo que se cual es el problema que nos esta dando , resulta que en la tabla pivote en el campo ingreso_id no puede estar null , agregue campos y resulta que si funciono , pero en el caso de los otros registros que contienen campos null , me arroja el erorr , como crees que debo solucionarlo.

Comment: muchas Gracias Por tu tiempo amigoo . lo logre solucionar con el helper que mencionaste ..TE LO AGRADEZCO !!!!!!